# Latest OpenKM 6.3.x source download missing frontend folder

Tags: github, binary, frontend, windows-installer, openkm

I understand the latest version of OpenKM CE is 6.3.12, is that right? I am looking for a download of the latest openKM  which includes the frontend folder and associated JS missed out in the source code download at githut page as of today. This folder is found in the setup package so is it safe copying over and recompiling? Wouldn't that create some inconsistency and bugs?

I tried writing to the openKM community but to no avail.